# API authorization using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some problems with api authorisation of leadstar.pl service

An example of php request is as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
$curl,
array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://leadstar.pl/api/programs",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
'partner_id' => yyy,
'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'product_id' => 2
),
)
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
$result = json_decode($response);
}
```

I want to convert it to python3 using requests or httpx

My try:

```
import httpx

params = {
    'partner_id': 'xxxx',
    'api_key': 'xxxx'
}

r = httpx.post('https://leadstar.pl/api/programs', params=params, verify=False)

print(r.text)
```

which gives 401 error. Unauthorised access

Answer (score 0):

Just a little change and it works. I forgot that when I do a post reguest I have to use 'data' instead of params.

```
import httpx

params = {
    'partner_id': 'xxxx',
    'api_key': 'xxxx'
}

r = httpx.post('https://leadstar.pl/api/programs', data=params, verify=False)

print(r.text)
```

Solved.